# Custom PHP endpoint for a plugin's AJAX call

Tags: ajax, javascript

I am writing a plugin for the first time, and I have a problem.

I am using AJAX in my plugin. My JavaScript file is in the folder `../wp-content/plugins/myplugin/js/` , and in it I am trying to call a PHP file, which is in the folder `../wp-content/plugins/myplugin/`

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/myfile.php?myparam=" + myparam,
    context: document.body
});
```

My question is: How can I get this URL reference work independent of, where the user installed the plugin.
Because when for example a user install this plugin in `http://localhost/subdir/`, the reference is not correct.
Can I somehow create a relative link ?

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you shouldn't call your own PHP file. You should use `admin-ajax` endpoint. [Documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

On admin side, you could use ajaxurl to get URL for AJAX calls. On front side you have to declare by yourself variable with url. This is written in documentation:

> **Note**: Unlike on the admin side, the ajaxurl javascript global does not get automatically defined for you, unless you have BuddyPress or another Ajax-reliant plugin installed. So instead of relying on a global javascript variable, declare a javascript namespace object with its own property, ajaxurl. You might also use wp_localize_script() to make the URL available to your script, and generate it using this expression: admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )

This should resolve problem:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'front_ajaxurl' );
function front_ajaxurl() {
    wp_register_script( 'admin_ajax_front', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'script.js' );
    $translation_array = array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
    );
    wp_localize_script( 'admin_ajax_front', 'front', $translation_array );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'admin_ajax_font', false, array(), false, true ); // last param set to true will enqueue script on footer
}
```

And then in your JS file:

```
$.ajax({
    url: front.ajaxurl,
    ...
})
```

Comment: Mixing up JavaScript and PHP code isn't a good practice. As the documentation quote says I would go with `wp_localize_script()`. That ensures that the variable will be defined before the script that depends on it will be loaded.

Comment: Even better than `wp_localize_script()`, you can use [`wp_add_inline_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/) since WordPress 4.5. This functions allows to print inline scripts within the great WordPress dependencies manager system, and not only limited to a JavaScript Object like `wp_add_inline_script()`.

Comment: i am still not getting it ... i still dont know how i refer to myfile.php and where ? will i make it into a function or how ? pls give me a hint, im lost

Comment: If you really need to call file from your plugin you could do it by `plugin_dir_url(__FILE__)`

Comment: i need to call myfile.php in my js as i showed in my question, of course, thats what i need ajax for. Its not clear to me also, if i should put admin-ajax.php in ajaxurl, or if its myfile.php i should put there instead ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm a beginner, but this worked for me

Add the following in functions.php. Note that 'wp_ajax' is a prefix by convention and 'do_something' is my arbitrarily chosen action name:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_do_something', 'do_something' );

function do_something() {
    //really, go ahead, do something
    die("return something");
}
```

To make the ajax call from the browser (client side), I was able to find my endpoint using `wp.ajax.settings.url`. `wp` global var is defined on the window object.

```
//do_something here must match above, you can add other params to this obj
var data = { action: 'do_something' };
jQuery.post(wp.ajax.settings.url, data, function(response) {
    console.log('Result: ' + response);
});
```

I have WordPress 4.6.1 (latest on time of writing) and some plugins installed. I referred to this reference that incorrectly says that ajaxurl is defined, but it's not in my case: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue.

I wanted to use my own endpoint instead the admin-ajax endpoint because I have rewrite rules populating all the variables I need to run the ajax actions.

Thus, using (as said [in the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins))

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var data = {
        'action': 'my_action',
        'whatever': ajax_object.we_value      // We pass php values differently!
    };
    jQuery.post(ajax_object.ajax_url, data, function(response) {
        alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
    });
});
```

and

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action' );
```

just makes my code more complicated.

I ended up doing this and it seems to work:

```
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: MYCUSTOMENDPOINT?ajax_action,
        dataType: 'json',
        ...
```

combined with:

```
    add_action( 'init', 'rewrite_rules');
    add_filter( 'template_include','handle_ajax_action');

function rewrite_rules(){
    add_rewrite_tag(
        '%ajax_action%',
        '([^&]+)'
    );
}

function handle_ajax_action($template){

    $success = null;

    // since the "ajax" query variable does not require a value, we need to check for its existence
    if ( !$action = get_query_var( 'ajax_action' ) ) return $template; //ajax action does not exists

    $result = array(
        'input' =>  $_REQUEST,
        'message'=> null,
        'success'=> null,
    );

    $success = ...

    if ( is_wp_error($success) ){
        $result['success'] = false;
        $result['message'] = $success->get_error_message();

    }else{
        $result['success'] = $success;
    }

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    send_nosniff_header();
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');

    wp_send_json( $result );  

}
```