# download link for uploaded images for wordpress

Tags: images

Is there a way have a download link so that users can directly download uploaded images on a wordpress theme?

I have seen this guide for something like this http://fcontheweb.com/articles/force_download/ but it is not wordpress specific and was not able to get it to work

Is there something easier to implement?

Currently i am able to link directly to the image and users are able to view the image in the browser but i want users to be able to download instead.

thanks

Comment: Yes, that is what you'll have to do: set a [`Content-Disposition: attachment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header, which means create a new endpoint to make the request to which will add the header and stream the file, like your example code. I haven't done this for WordPress but at first glance it looks like you could use [admin_ajax](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/233338/custom-php-endpoint-for-a-plugins-ajax-call) or maybe [the REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/)

Comment: hmm dont know how to do that? is it too complicated to do as an answer i can follow?

Comment: I haven't tried it either, sorry. I don't know anything more than the pages I linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to use the [HTML5 download](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp) attribute for that.  So just make your links look like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_url($id); ?>" download>Download Image</a>
```

where `$id` is the attachment ID

Comment: wow..you are the man!!!..worked like a champ